# How to use machine learning to create combine of opposite images side by side

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

Inspired by: [Two Worlds Pictures](https://www.instagram.com/ugurgallen/)

[image]
[image]

I just want to create a Machine Learning Model that can automatically combine the opposite images into 1 image.

I am thinking about 2 possible solutions:

1. [Pose Estimation](https://medium.com/tensorflow/move-mirror-an-ai-experiment-with-pose-estimation-in-the-browser-using-tensorflow-js-2f7b769f9b23): Detect humans and their poses from image data and search an archive by pose, but totally out of context.
2. [Land Lines](https://developers.google.com/web/showcase/2016/land-lines): explore similar lines.

It's just my ideas, do you have any recommendations? 
Thanks